# How to resort a mutableStateOf(listOf<PojoObject>())?

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have a populated:

```
data class PojoObject(val id: Int, val name: String)

val listData = mutableStateOf(listOf<PojoObject>())
//..
listData.value = anotherList.map{//..}
```

Assuming listData is already sorted by increasing id.
How can I resort the `listData` object by lets say `name` in alphabetic order?

I would prefer to operate on listItem directly without wrapping it like:

```
listData.value = listData.component1().map{//..}.sort{//..}
```

Comment: `anotherList.map { /* ... */ }.sortBy { it.name }`

Comment: No. That was just symbolic. I dont have access to 'anotherList'. I only have acces to *listData*

Comment: What's the problem with `listData.value = listData.value.sortedWith(compareBy { it.name })`?